# How to add ZAP alert through ZAP python api?

Tags: security, owasp, zap

I am using python ZAP api (ZAPv2) to write a automation script to scan our site and generate alert report, and now I also integrate python nmap to scan our sites

however, if nmap have some scan issues, i want to add this kind of issues into ZAP alert report

is there any way to do that ? does ZAP api expose services to add the alert ? just like:

```
z.core.add_alert(....)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly no, there is no API call for adding an alert.
But there should be - I've just raised this enhancement request: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/5303

Comment: oh, thanks ! i know that the zap community script supports this function, raiseAlert(), but ZAPv2 doesn't, lol

Comment: Yeah, thats because those scripts run inside ZAP and have access to all of the internal methods. If you really need to you could always write an extender script which adds an API end point for this. Or even better send in a PR which adds it to ZAP :D I've been meaning to add this for a while but too many other things are higher priority :/